# sql how to sum count in a month

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables. and i have a sql which can show time ,date , employee_id, and count the repeat id. Now I want to allowed the  system can sum of count the all the name which start with letter 'L',  and show everyday's sum of count all employee with name start with letter 'L'

```
select distinct a.employee_id,b.name,a.type,a.date,a.time,count(*) 
from deal_records a, staff_table b 
where a.employee_id = b.employee_id && a.date>='2017-1-1' 
  and a.date <'2017-2-1'&& b.name like "L%" 
group by a.employee_id;
```

[The format should be looks like below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDe3D.png)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS properly. Choose mysl or sql-server but not both

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: Your implicit join syntax is significantly antiquated. Try usiung [JOIN syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: Kindly add table structures for better response!

Comment: Also, please provide sample data and expected output (as a sample of the data). Please provide this as text in the question, not as an image.

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Sorry, i am using MySQL..not sql server

Answer (score 0):

Having both `select distinct` and `group by` in a single query smells a lot, please extend the `group by` clause appropriately.

About answering the question, replace `count(*)` with `sum(case when b.name like 'L%' then 1 end)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.employee_id,b.name,a.type,a.date,a.time,
sum( case when b.name like "L%" 1 else 0 end) as all_count
from deal_records a, staff_table b 
where a.employee_id = b.employee_id 
&& trunc(a.date) between to_date('01.01.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY') and to_date('01.02.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
group by a.employee_id
order by trunc(a.date)
```